# Cannot access hdf5 array from a thread

Tags: multithreading, h5py

I am using h5py processing the array in several threads:

```
def process(start, end, dataset):
    for i in xrange(start, end):
        # Do something with dataset[i]

f = h5py.File(path, 'r')
dataset = f[...]

worker = [threading.Thread(target=process, args=(start, end, dataset)) \
          for start, end in ...]
```

I get an error when accessing the array from the thread

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/h5py/_hl/dataset.py", line 367, in __getitem__
    if self._local.astype is not None:
AttributeError: 'thread._local' object has no attribute 'astype'
```

I have really no clue why this happens :/, I can access `dtype` and `shape`, but on access of any slice I get this error.

---

**Edit:**

Calling

```
process(0, len(dataset), dataset)
```

in the main thread works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a full example that reproduces the error? Please also mention the versions of Python, h5py, and the hdf5 library that you're using, as well as your OS.

The following code works with my setup, does it work on yours?

```py
import threading
import h5py
import numpy as np

db = h5py.File('/tmp/test.h5', 'w')
dataset = db.create_dataset("mydata", data=np.random.random((10,)))

def process(start, end, dataset):
    for i in xrange(start, end):
        print(dataset[i])

workers = [threading.Thread(target=process, args=(start, end, dataset))
           for start, end in [[1,2], [3,4]]]
workers[0].start()
workers[1].start()
db.close()
```

May I ask why you are using threads to process your hdf5 file? Note that hdf5 does not provide thread-level concurrency. Although the above example "works" (premise: hdf5 compiled with "threadsafe" option), the two operations will run sequentially. Hdf5 operations are blocking and do not release the global interpreter lock during I/O, which prevents threads from running in parallel.

If you want your code to be executed in parallel, you have to use processes instead of threads. Note, however, that parallel reading **and** writing is safe only with the MPI version of h5py/hdf5.

Comment: I'm using a big dataset, computing the phase correlation for image registration on every frame of a dataset. It takes some computational time. I/O operations thus can be sequential. I just need some chunked part of the array in memory to be processed.

The above code does not work in my setup, strangely, I can use the function `read_direct` and everything works fine. Writing to the dataset can also be done in the threads (Ofc locking everything to be sequential). So I guess there is some different behaviour between `read_direct` and `__get_item__`?

Comment: The global interpreter lock is just on I/Os? After reading/writing the lock is released and threads run in parallel again?

Comment: You may want to buy this book from the main author of h5py:
http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920030249.do

Comment: I can't tell what's going on. What package versions and OS do you use?
Be careful with threads: multithreaded code in pure Python is not going to run in parallel. The GIL prevents this. Although I/O can happen in the background (not true for h5py), CPU-bound operations always run sequentally. If you want to take advantage of your CPU cores, use `multiprocessing` instead of `threading`. An alternative might be to write your time-critical code with Cython or Numba instead of pure Python. They both allow to release the GIL and, hence, provide true thread-concurrency.

Comment: PS: Sorry that the remark on the book came first (unintentionally pressed enter). Also, I am not the author of the book and don't benefit from anyone buying it.

Comment: OS version is Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS. h5py version is 2.2.1. Python's version is 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
It was solved by updating h5py (from 2.2 to to 2.6).

Comment: For reference, I recently had the same problem with 2.7.0 and fixed it by *downgrading* to 2.6.0.